# sql subqueries and group by

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having an assignment for my sql class which i can't seem to figure out. This is the description of the select wanted:

Show all employees of which the salary is higher than the average of the colleagues in their department, only for the departments with at least 4 employees.

I've been able to find parts of the query like

```
select ename 
  from emp
 where sal > any (select avg(sal) 
                    from emp 
                  group by 
                         deptno);
```

to get the names of the employees which earn more than the avg.

or

```
select count(deptno) 
  from emp
group by 
       deptno having count(deptno) > 4;
```

to getthe number of employees in each department.

But somehow it doesn't work linking them together. Maybe someone can help me shine a light on this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your second query in with an AND clause:

```
select ename 
  from emp
 where sal > any (select avg(sal) 
                    from emp 
                  group by 
                         deptno)
and deptno in (select deptno
               from emp
               group by 
               deptno having count(deptno) > 4);
```

Comment: a simple solution. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Having Clause** in Conjunction with **Group By**

```
select ename 
  from emp
 where sal > any (select avg(sal) 
                    from emp 
                  group by 
                         deptno) 
having count(*)>4;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ename 
  from (
        select deptno, count(deptno) 
        from emp
        group by deptno
        having count(deptno) > 4) valid_depts join emp ON emp.deptno=valid_depts.deptno
 where sal > any (select avg(sal) 
                    from emp 
                   group deptno);
```